# Autofac, MakeGenericMethod.Invoke not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, reflection, autofac, nopcommerce

I tried to use Autofac `IRegistrationSource` resolve other interface,but it's not working. Below is my code:

```
public class SettingsSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    static readonly MethodInfo BuildMethod = typeof(SettingsSource).GetMethod(
        "BuildRegistration",
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
            Service service,
            Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrations)
    {
        var ts = service as TypedService;
        if (ts != null && typeof(ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(ts.ServiceType))
        {
            var buildMethod = BuildMethod.MakeGenericMethod(ts.ServiceType);
            yield return (IComponentRegistration)buildMethod.Invoke(null, null);
        }
    }

    static IComponentRegistration BuildRegistration<TSettings>()
        where TSettings : ISettings, new()
    {
        return RegistrationBuilder
            .ForDelegate((c, p) =>
            {
                return c.Resolve<ISettingService>().LoadSetting<TSettings>();
            })
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .CreateRegistration();
    }

    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents { get { return false; } }
}
```

private method c.Resolve().LoadSetting() can't be fired.

I checked bellow links, still can't figure out why.
[Autofac. How to use custom method(property) to resolve some interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851775/autofac-how-to-use-custom-methodproperty-to-resolve-some-interface)

http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/

anyone can give a clue?

Thanks

Comment: The code you provide is a verbatim copy of the registration for settings providers in nopcommerce. Therefore you can be sure it works as intended, otherwise you would have no settings access at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Marco, Yes,It's from nopcommerce. I want to implement system setting framework like nopcommerce.  All the settings operated by ISettingService and registered when system start up. But I found private function in the fordelegate is not fired.

Comment: Have you registered the registrationsource? You first need to debug the RegistrationsFor method to be sure it is called and executes the yield return clause when resolving a class that inherits ISettings. There is where you need to set  the breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, RegistrationsFor can be called, BuildRegistration<TSettings>() can be called as well. But LoadSetting<TSettings>() can not reached.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code, from nopCommerce, works perfectly. I have it used myself, also, and works great. So, if it is not working, the problem will be somewhere in the code you don't show, but I sincerely doubt there is any and most likely it is working already.

Assuming the `BuildRegistration` method is reached, as per your comments, it will only return a dependency rule, not the service instance itself. The  `c.Resolve<ISettingService>()` call will be executed later, lazily, when needed. You need to set the breakpoint inside the lambda, to see it happening.

Note that `BuildRegistration` will only be called once for each class implementing ISettings. After that, Autofac will use the provided rule.

Comment: You can check my previous answer about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944127/how-to-load-records-from-setting-table-of-nopcommerce-v3-5/32987318#32987318

Comment: Thanks Marco, as I mentioned BuildRegistration can be reached, I tried to set breakpoint inside the lambda already, but nothing happen, did not triggered at all, that's why I know LoadingSetting<T>() does not reached.

Comment: @LLI, as mentioned, you need to provide the remaining code (autofac registration, settings class and usage) as the code you have already provided is correct.